# Extending a method that has a return type

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend a method that already has a return type.  For example:

```
IQueryable<int> GetCategoryIds()
```

So, I can use this as follows:

```
IQueryable<int> categories = GetCategoryIds();
```

And I'm currently doing:

```
IQueryable<int> categories = GetCategoryIds().Select(c => new Client() { ClientId == c.clientId });
```

This works, but I don't want to do that `Select` statement. I'd rather do an extension method that excepts a `type` so I can use Reflection in the extension method to determine the type etc. and return the results according.  The extension method would be something like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> LovelyExtension(this T objectType, int clientId)
```

Then I can use this extension like (hopefully):

```
IQueryable<int> categories = GetCategoryIds().LovelyExtension<int>(1);
```

Is this possible?  When I tried it, I got an error because the `GetCategoryIds` return type wasn't the same as the extension method.  But, this works with the `Select` statement.

Comment: Your Select version doesn't make sense - it should be returning `IEnumerable<Client>`, not `List<int>`, so your assignment to `categories` should fail to compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to write an extension on `Type` (your example is not doing it either). You need an extension on `IQueryable<T>`. You can do it like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> LovelyExtension<T>(this IQueryable<T> input, int clientId) {
    Type inputType = typeof(T);
    // Here you can use reflection if you need to: inputType corresponds to the type of T
    // Create an instance of IQueryable<T>, and return it to the caller.
}
```

Comment: I think that I got myself muddle up with the extensions part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your signature from,

```
public static IQueryable<T> LovelyExtension(this T objectType, int clientId)
```

to

```
public static T LovelyExtension(this T objectType, int clientId)
```

or

```
public static IQueryable<T> LovelyExtension(this IQuerable<T> objectType, int clientId)
```

GetCategoryIds() returns an IQuerable (which is what your passing into LovelyExtension's objectType, your return type based on your original signature becomes IQuerable> which obviously won't match what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to declare an interface on your client class and add a constratint to your extension method. Take a look at this post [generic extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835843/generic-extension-method)